# threw an unexpected exception: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@'

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

This query is working fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM public.mynotes
WHERE to_tsvector('russian', atext) @@ plainto_tsquery('russian', 'some phrase');
```

I have a method with same query string:

```
String qString = "from MynotesEntity where to_tsvector (" +
                 lang + ", atext) @@ plainto_tsquery(" +
                 lang + ", " + phrase + ")";
Query query = session.createQuery(qString);
mynotesEntityList = query.list();
```

double symbol @ "@@" is marked by red line, but application is run on.

When app is run on, i get a exception like this:

> threw an unexpected exception: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@' [from ru.javastudy.gwtPersistence.shared.MynotesEntity where to_tsvector ('russian', atext) @@ plainto_tsquery('russian', 'some phrase')]

can anybody help me? :(

Comment: There is http://ru.stackoverflow.com/ though.

Comment: You need to use **native SQL** in Hibernate. JPQL does not understand regular SQL nor SQL extensions like Postgres' full text search